# Диаграмма на веб странице

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, веб-программирование

Добрый день. Каким образом можно реализовать диаграмму доступности серверов по SNMP. Т.е. меня интересует как без помощи библиотек реализовать график. На чем? На JS или можно просто HTML и CSS применить?

По реализации: Я записываю каждые 10 секунд данные о пингах с сервера. Т.е. сервер мониторинга каждые 10 секунд пингует другой сервер. Ответ записывается в базу данных. Эти все значения надо вывести на экран ввиде диаграммы. Буду рад помощи.

Comment: вы хоть опишите какой вид диаграммы вы себе представляете?

Comment: можно отрисовывать различные диаграммы на canvas